# set pre content for joomla module

Tags: php, joomla3.2

How can i set pre content description for **Joomla module** .
I need this content to use in:

```
templates/{templateName}/html/mod_articles_news/default.php
```

for show some description about current module.
Thanks.

Comment: i had tried  to add a params into mod_articles_latest.xml look like <field ... ></field> then administrator could set this params as pre content description but after upgrade joomla this params has been removed.

Comment: You cant edit the xml file for modules and expect them to stay put for updates.